# Even sets of integers

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Given an array of integers `heights` I would like to split these into `n` sets, each with equal `totalHeight` (sum of the values in set), or as close to as possible. There must be a fixed distance, `gap`, between each value in a set.  Sets do not have to have the same number of values.

For example, supposing:

- `heights[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] = [120, 78, 110, 95, 125, 95]`
- `n` = 3
- `gaps` = 10

Possible arrangements would be:

- `a[0, 1], b[2, 3], c[4, 5]` giving `totalHeight` values of

  - `a = heights[0] + gap + heights[1] = 120 + 10 + 78 = 208`
  - `b = heights[2] + gap + heights[3] = 110 + 10 + 95 = 215`
  - `c = heights[4] + gap + heights[5] = 125 + 10 + 95 = 230`
- `a[0], b[1, 2, 3], c[4, 5]` giving `totalHeight` values of

  - `a = heights[0] = 120`
  - `b = heights[1] + gap + heights[2] + gap + heights[3] = 303`
  - `c = heights[4] + gap + heights[5] = 125 + 10 + 95 = 230`

And so on. I want to find the combination that gives the most evenly-sized sets. So in this example the first combination is better since it gives an overall error of:

```
max - min = 230 - 208 = 22
```

Whereas the second combination gives an error of 183. I'm trying to do this in JavaScript, but I'm just looking for some sort of outline of an algorithm. Pseudo code or whatever would be great. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**MY POOR ATTEMPTS:** Obviously one way of solving this would be to just try every possible combination. That would be horrible though once `heights` gets large.

Another method I tried is to get the expected mean height of the sets, calculated as the sum of the values in `height` / `n`. Then I tried to fill each set individually by getting as close to this average as possible. It works alright in some cases, but it's too slow.

**NOTE:** If it helps, I would be happy to have symmetric sets. So for example, with sets (a, b c), a = b. Or with five sets (a, b, c, d, e), a = b and c = d. I think this would be even more difficult to implement but I could be wrong.

**EDIT:** For anyone who may be interested, the best I could come up with was the following algorithm:

- Sort `heights` in descending order.
- Create `n` sets.
- Put the first `n` values from `heights` into the first slot of each set. i.e. put the `n` largest values at the start of each set. Remove the values from `heights` as they are added.
- While `heights.count` > 0

  - Find the smallest `totalHeight` (including `gap`) in each of the `n` sets.
  - Add the next value in `heights` to this set (and remove the value from `heights`).
- Then there's some little algorithm at the end where each set can make `x` number of swaps with the other sets, if the `totalHeight` gets closer to the average. I'm keeping `x` small because this process could go on forever.

It's not terrible, but obviously not perfect.

Comment: This feels like an instance of the [Scheduling problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling).

Comment: Your problem is [NP complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) but you might have a shot at an efficient dynamic programming solution if the heights are not too large.

Comment: @You: Well, its NP complete so it feels like an instance of a lot of stuff :)

Comment: I wasted 2 hours of my life, I misunderstood the question and well, if someone wants to separate randomly an array in n groups, and sum their values with a gap, here it is http://jsfiddle.net/zcgpy/3/

Comment: @missingno: I know. The Scheduling problem was the one I could think of a reduction to, but I was too tired to formalize it :).

Comment: @ajax333221 thanks for the effort. I'm going to try modify what you've done there to see if it performs better than the algorithm I ended up with (see my edit).

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it is NP-complete and reducible to [Subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) or more precisely to [Partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach - finding the mean (height / n), then attempting to fill sets with a mean as close as possible seems like a good practical approach. You say this is too slow... the following implementation is O(n*m log n) where m is the maximum number of elements allowed in a set. If m can be very large, then this could be quite slow, however if m is constrained to be within a certain range then it could approach O(n log n) which is about as fast as you are going to get.

```
   Find the mean height of all values. h_mean = Sum(h) / n; O(n).
   Sort all heights. O(n log n).
   Examine the highest and lowest height. 
   Add the value which is furthest from the mean to a new set.
   Remove this value from the sorted heights.
   Repeat for max_number allowed in set = 1 .. m (m < n / 2)
   {
      Repeat:
      {
         If the set mean is higher than the mean.
            Add the lowest value from the sorted heights.
            Remove this value from the sorted heights.
         If the set mean is lower than the mean
            Add the highest value from the sorted heights.
            Remove this value from the sorted heights.
         Recalculate the set mean (taking account of the gap).
         If the new set mean is further from the h_mean than the last OR
            If the set has too many elements
           break
      }
      Until all numbers are used.
      Keep track of the standard deviations for this assignment. 
      If this assignment is the best so far, keep it.
   }
```

This isn't going to give a provably optimal solution, but it's simple and that has a lot going for it...

Note, in this algorithm, all sets have the same number of elements, m. You repeat an iteration for different values of m, say, 2, 3, 4 (note that m should be a factor of N). Each set ends up with approximately m * mean_height for total height.

*You may ask, well what if N is prime?*

Then clearly, one set will value short on total value.

*Does this mean this algorithm is useless?*

Not at all. It's simple and it should produce a good first attempt at a solution. You may wish to use this algorithm first, then refine the first result using optimization techniques (such as selective swapping of heights being sets).

Comment: Unless I don't understand fully, is this algorithm not going to produce sets with equal average heights? I want to produce sets with equal total heights.

Comment: I've added more clarification. I should stress this is a simple and crude approach, but I believe it has value in producing a "first guess" quickly. You then might consider refinement techniques that take this assignment and perturb it to produce a better solution.